# SQL command line error while defining foreign key in a create table command

Tags: sql, oracle, command-line

I have been working on a project of student information system and i got into a problem where I need to define a foreign key for a department table which would link to a student table. The statements are:-

```
Create Table Department
(
    deptID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    deptINTRO VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    deptPhone VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    deptADDRESS VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    deptManager VARCHAR(20) NULL,

    stuID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student(stuID)
);
```

> ERROR at line 7:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I am new to SQL BTW.

Comment: Need to see the `Student` table.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY` is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have such a Student table as below one, you may create with the following statement :

```
Create Table Student(stuID int PRIMARY KEY);

Create Table Department(
  deptID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  deptINTRO VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  deptPhone VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  deptADDRESS VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  deptManager VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  stuID int, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_stID FOREIGN KEY(stuID) REFERENCES Student(stuID)
);
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct ways to create referential integrity constraints in an Oracle CREATE TABLE statement: In-Line and Out-of-Line.

In-Line:

```
Create Table TableName(
  ID number not null CONSTRAINT TableName_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FK number not null CONSTRAINT TableName_FK1 REFERENCES ForeignTable(ID)
);
```

Out-Of-Line:

```
Create Table TableName(
  ID number not null,
  FK number not null,
  CONSTRAINT TableName_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT TableName_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES ForeignTable(ID)
);
```

In both cases naming the constraint (`CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name`) is optional.  In  your code you've mixed the two types of declarations by including the unnecessary `FOREIGN KEY` statement in what would otherwise be an In-Line constraint declaration.